# how to insert number inside the stacked bar?

Tags: tikz-pgf, bar-chart

I tried stacked graph but i need inside bar to set alphanumberic like p1,p2,p3.

My MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}          % to print charts
%\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
%\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        ybar stacked,
        nodes near coords,
        every node near coord/.append style=
{xshift=-15pt,yshift=-3pt,anchor=east,font=\footnotesize},
        xbar legend,
%         nodes near coords align={right},
        legend pos=outer north east,
        enlarge x limits={abs=1},
        enlarge y limits=false,
        bar width=35.5,width=10cm,height=13cm,
        % x axis
        xtick={1,2,3},
        xticklabels={p1,p2,p3},
        % y axis
        ymin=0,
        ylabel={Scheduling Length},
        xlabel={Processors},
        %yticklabels={0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,500},
      ]
      \addplot table [
        x=index,
        y=blue,
      ] {
index   blue            pink    gray    orange
1       44              29      00      00
2       45              23      08      23
3       09              17      09      10      
      };
      \addplot table [
        x=index,
        y=pink,
      ] {
index   blue            pink    gray    orange
1       44              29      00      00
2       45              23      08      23
3       09              17      09      10 
};
      \addplot table [
      x=index,
      y=gray,
      ] {
index   blue            pink    gray    orange
1       44              29      00      00
2       45              23      08      23
3       09              17      09      10 
      };
      \addplot table [
        x=index,
        y=orange,
      ] {
index   blue            pink    gray    orange
1       44              29      00      00
2       45              23      08      23
3       09              17      09      10
      };
      %\legend{First one,Second one,Third,Fourth}
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{Makespan for PETS}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

below diagram inside  number bar like that i needed. for P1 [ 2,8]

[image]

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean, can you try to explain in more detail what you mean?

Comment: @Torbjørn T, i edited in detail

Answer (score 4):

(I'm still not entirely sure exactly what you want, so if this misses the mark by a mile, please comment, and I'll change it if I can. There are four different parts here, each with a different setup.)

## Almost like your example

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}          % to print charts
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \pgfplotsset{
    /pgfplots/bar cycle list/.style={/pgfplots/cycle list={%
        {black,fill=white,mark=none},%
        {black,fill=white,mark=none},%
        {black,fill=white,mark=none},%
        {black,fill=white,mark=none},%
        }
    },
}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        ybar stacked,
        point meta=explicit symbolic,
        nodes near coords=\pgfplotspointmeta,
        every node near coord/.append style=
{anchor=north,fill=gray,minimum width=20pt,black},
        xbar legend,
%         nodes near coords align={right},
        legend pos=outer north east,
        enlarge x limits={abs=1},
        enlarge y limits=false,
        bar width=20pt,width=10cm,height=13cm,
        % x axis
        xtick={1,2,3},
        xticklabels={p1,p2,p3},
        % y axis
        ymin=0,
        ylabel={Scheduling Length},
        xlabel={Processors},
      ]
      \addplot table [
        x=index,
        y=blue,
       meta=meta
      ] {
index   blue            pink    gray    orange   meta
1       44              29      00      00       1
2       45              23      08      23       2
3       09              17      09      10       3
      };
      \addplot table [
        x=index,
        y=pink,
        meta=meta
      ] {
index   blue            pink    gray    orange  meta
1       44              29      00      00      4
2       45              23      08      23      5
3       09              17      09      10      6
};
      \addplot table [
      x=index,
      y=gray,
      meta=meta
      ] {
index   blue            pink    gray    orange  meta
1       44              29      00      00      \space
2       45              23      08      23      8
3       09              17      09      10      9
      };
      \addplot table [
        x=index,
        y=orange,
        meta=meta
      ] {
index   blue            pink    gray    orange   meta
1       44              29      00      00       \space
2       45              23      08      23       11
3       09              17      09      10       12
      };
      %\legend{First one,Second one,Third,Fourth}
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{Makespan for PETS}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

## Cumulative values

This is basically what you have. Just change the style for `every node near coord` to move it into the bar. As you're reading the same table multiple times, it's more convenient to save it to a macro first.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}          % to print charts
\pgfplotstableread{
index   blue            pink    gray    orange
1       44              29      00      00      
2       45              23      08      23      
3       09              17      09      10  
}\DataForBars
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        ybar stacked,
        nodes near coords,
        every node near coord/.append style=
{anchor=north},
        xbar legend,
%         nodes near coords align={right},
        legend pos=outer north east,
        enlarge x limits={abs=1},
        enlarge y limits=false,
        bar width=35.5,width=10cm,height=13cm,
        % x axis
        xtick={1,2,3},
        xticklabels={p1,p2,p3},
        % y axis
        ymin=0,
        ylabel={Scheduling Length},
        xlabel={Processors},
      ]
      \addplot table [
        x=index,
        y=blue,
      ] {\DataForBars};
      \addplot table [
        x=index,
        y=pink,
      ] {\DataForBars};
      \addplot table [
      x=index,
      y=gray,
      ] {\DataForBars};
      \addplot table [
        x=index,
        y=orange,
      ] {\DataForBars};
      %\legend{First one,Second one,Third,Fourth}
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{Makespan for PETS}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

## Value of each part of the stack

For `compat=1.9` and newer, the default behaviour is to place the height of each part of the "stack" in the middle of the bar, so adding something like `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}` gives you that.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}          % to print charts
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\pgfplotstableread{
index   blue            pink    gray    orange
1       44              29      00      00      
2       45              23      08      23      
3       09              17      09      10  
}\DataForBars
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        ybar stacked,
        nodes near coords,
        xbar legend,
        legend pos=outer north east,
        enlarge x limits={abs=1},
        enlarge y limits=false,
        bar width=0.5,
        width=10cm,height=13cm,
        % x axis
        xtick={1,2,3},
        xticklabels={p1,p2,p3},
        % y axis
        ymin=0,
        ylabel={Scheduling Length},
        xlabel={Processors},
      ]
      \addplot table [
        x=index,
        y=blue,
      ] {\DataForBars};
      \addplot table [
        x=index,
        y=pink,
      ] {\DataForBars};
      \addplot table [
      x=index,
      y=gray,
      ] {\DataForBars};
      \addplot table [
        x=index,
        y=orange,
      ] {\DataForBars};
      %\legend{First one,Second one,Third,Fourth}
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{Makespan for PETS}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

## Custom texts

By adding `point meta=explicit symbolic,nodes near coords=\pgfplotspointmeta` to the axis option, and a new column in the table (here called `meta`) you can add custom texts to the bars. The `\space` you see a couple of places is just a hack to avoid the overlapping values you get due to the zero-values in the table.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}          % to print charts
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        ybar stacked,
        point meta=explicit symbolic,
        nodes near coords=\pgfplotspointmeta,
        every node near coord/.append style=
{anchor=north},
        xbar legend,
%         nodes near coords align={right},
        legend pos=outer north east,
        enlarge x limits={abs=1},
        enlarge y limits=false,
        bar width=35.5,width=10cm,height=13cm,
        % x axis
        xtick={1,2,3},
        xticklabels={p1,p2,p3},
        % y axis
        ymin=0,
        ylabel={Scheduling Length},
        xlabel={Processors},
      ]
      \addplot table [
        x=index,
        y=blue,
       meta=meta
      ] {
index   blue            pink    gray    orange   meta
1       44              29      00      00       1
2       45              23      08      23       2
3       09              17      09      10       3
      };
      \addplot table [
        x=index,
        y=pink,
        meta=meta
      ] {
index   blue            pink    gray    orange  meta
1       44              29      00      00      \space
2       45              23      08      23      5
3       09              17      09      10      6
};
      \addplot table [
      x=index,
      y=gray,
      meta=meta
      ] {
index   blue            pink    gray    orange  meta
1       44              29      00      00      \space
2       45              23      08      23      8
3       09              17      09      10      9
      };
      \addplot table [
        x=index,
        y=orange,
        meta=meta
      ] {
index   blue            pink    gray    orange   meta
1       44              29      00      00       10
2       45              23      08      23       11
3       09              17      09      10       12
      };
      %\legend{First one,Second one,Third,Fourth}
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{Makespan for PETS}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```